# Алгоритм к логической задаче

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Допустим есть безграничное кол-во купюр, номиналами a, b и c 
Как определить максимальное количество купюр сумма которых будет равна N ? 
Была идея находить минимальный номинал, потом находить такое максимальное k при котором k*min <= N, а потом циклом отнимать 1 от k и подставлять другие номиналы, пока это все не будет == N 
Но естественно это срабатывает далеко не всегда, и слишком долго работает на больших числах 
Какой алгоритм действий ко всему этому можно придумать?
p.s. решение задачи должно быть без использования рекурсии и функций

Comment: почитайте про Задачу о ранце и ее вариации

Comment: [Задача о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, по логике (принимая `a < b < c`) запишем функцию `count(N)` так:

Если `N==0` - возвращаем 0.
Если `N < a` - сообщаем об ошибке.
Если `N` делится на `a` - то функция возвращает `N/a`.
Если нет - то ищем максимум `count(N-b)` и `count(N-c)`, и возвращаем его + 1.

Смотрим, и если работает медленно - привязываем к этому мемоизацию.

Ищем, само собой, `count(N)`...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: К сожалению в условии решения задачи нельзя использовать циклы, но все равно благодарю за вариант

Comment: @Bogdan Bida: Это где такое сказано в условии задачи? Перечитал пять раз - в упор не вижу. При этом вы сами там говорите: "циклом отнимать".

Comment: Мой косяк, забыл упомянуть (думал решение сразу делается одной формулой или парой циклов)

Comment: Ну тогда просто разверните динамическое программирование в обратную сторону и стройте тот же массив значений в обратном порядке...